# What are the upsides and downsides for a company to list all their patents on their website?

Tags: patent-search

Some company lists their patents on their website, e.g. [Peloton's website](https://www.onepeloton.com/legal/patents) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20230912180153/https://www.onepeloton.com/legal/patents)).

What are the upsides and downsides for a company to list all their patents on their website?

Answer (score 1):

I'd be speculating, but I'd guess that listing the patents makes it easier to claim ["willful infringement"](https://www.upcounsel.com/willful-infringement#:%7E:text=5%20min%20read-,Willful%20Infringement%3A%20What%20Is%20It%3F,infringed%20the%20patent%20or%20copyright) for which there may be enhanced damages.

As for downsides, if you are a patent troll, it might be in your interest to not publicize your IP in the hopes of catching someone using it inadvertently.